# Xamarin WebView load URL after special page

Tags: android, xamarin, webview

Hello I try to authenticate some site. After login page that site redirect my webview to another site and new url has important parameter for me. This page return me error

"Web page is not available net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Now after passed to login page I get parameter from new url and I try to redirect webview to my page.

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        WebView app_view = null;
        WebSettings app_web_settings = null;
        WebChromeClient web_client;
        MyWebViewClient my_web_client;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
          base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

          // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
          SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
          try
          {
            app_view = FindViewById(Resource.Id.webViewApp) as WebView;
            app_web_settings = app_view.Settings;
            app_web_settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            app_web_settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
            app_web_settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
            app_web_settings.DatabaseEnabled = true;
            app_web_settings.SetRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.High);
            app_view.SetLayerType(LayerType.Hardware, null);
            my_web_client = new MyWebViewClient(this);
            web_client = new WebChromeClient();
            app_view.SetWebViewClient(my_web_client);
            app_view.SetWebChromeClient(web_client);

            string app_url = "http://examplesite.com";
            app_view.LoadUrl(app_url);
            app_view.AddJavascriptInterface(new Foo(this), "foo");
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
            Console.WriteLine("Error -> " + ex.ToString());
          }
        }
    }




 public class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient
  {
    MainActivity act;
    public MyWebViewClient(MainActivity activity)
    {
      this.act = activity;
    }
    public override void OnPageStarted(WebView view, string url, Android.Graphics.Bitmap favicon)
    {
        base.OnPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        if (url.Length > 7)
        {
          int index = url.IndexOf("?code=");
          if (index > -1)
          {
           //------------------------------
           // In this line, I want to redirect my page
           view.LoadUrl("file:///android_asset/app_pages/home.html"); 
          }
        } 
    }

    public override void OnReceivedError(WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error)
    {
        base.OnReceivedError(view, request, error);        
        //------------------------------
        // In this line, I want to redirect my page
        view.LoadUrl("file:///android_asset/app_pages/home.html");   
    }

    public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
    {
        base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
    }

}
```

I try to loadURL in OnPageStarted or OnReceivedError events. But webview can't load the this URL.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to overwrite `ShouldOverrideUrlLoading` method in your **MyWebViewClient** :

```
public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request)
        {
            string url = request.Url.ToString();
            if (url.Length > 7)
            {
                int index = url.IndexOf("?code=");
                if (index > -1)
                {
                    //------------------------------
                    // In this line, I want to redirect my page
                    view.LoadUrl("file:///android_asset/app_pages/home.html");
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: It works thank you. But I changed it little bit. I return true only if conditional true. Otherwise I can't change the URL of webview anyway.